# Do any sound designers who specialize solely in UI sound for products (apps, wearables, etc) exist?

Tags: sound, design, ui

Are there any sound designers who only work at composing/producing sound for products such as digital applications, wearables, home electronics, appliances, etc., or is it too small of a market for specialization?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know - but I used to specialise entirely in portable keyboards [tiny sample sets, GM, music styles etc], which has got to be a pretty small market bracket, so possibly it could be done. You might need to build a close association with a major to make it pay, though.

Answer (score 1):

[Boom libraries](http://www.boomlibrary.com) do one. I've not heard it but all their libraries are great.

Answer (score 1):

Henry Daw is ex-Nokia, ex-Microsoft and has set up to do exactly that. His studio is called Oblique Sound http://www.obliquesound.com/

Just plugging a mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure [this cool dj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orkidea) did a lot of SFX for apps and phones back in the day.

Another certain truth is that sound design is a broad discipline and specializing in one field for marketing purposes will only have you lacking in other directions.